# Case function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Why this is not working? I want to display a new column `seasons` with the correct season for each student's date of birth.

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)
);
```

query:

```
SELECT *, CASE
    WHEN (1 <= MONTH(`birth_date`))
     AND (MONTH(`birth_date` <= 3)) THEN 'winter'
    WHEN (MONTH(`birth_date` <= 6)) THEN 'spring'
    WHEN (MONTH(`birth_date` <= 9)) THEN 'summer'
    WHEN (MONTH(`birth_date` <= 12)) THEN 'autumn'
END AS `seasons`
FROM `students`;
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/giQczqKvJNbdCJFwevJCk8/1)

Comment: This should work as expected except for incorrect dates (dates with 0 month).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is incorrect. You have incorrect conditions:

1. You must use `(MONTH(birth_date) <= 12)` instead of `(MONTH(birth_date <= 12))`
2. You use 'less or equal' condition for example `MONTH(birth_date) <= 3` but the third month is spring, the sixth month is summer.

Try the following query

```
SELECT *,
  CASE 
  WHEN (MONTH(birth_date) BETWEEN 3 AND 5) THEN 'spring'
  WHEN (MONTH(birth_date) BETWEEN 6 AND 8) THEN 'summer'
  WHEN (MONTH(birth_date) BETWEEN 9 AND 11) THEN 'autumn'
  ELSE 'winter'
  END AS seasons
FROM students;
```

Comment: Spring starts on March 21. Most of March is winter, not spring. The same with all the other seasons.

Comment: Alright! Working one: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/giQczqKvJNbdCJFwevJCk8/6

Comment: @Orion note that this has changed the definition of what months are part of each season, when compared to your version...as Barmar points out above, it's not necessarily a correct change, depending on your interpretation. Just to ensure you're fully aware.

Comment: @Barmar it depends on a specific country. For example, spring starts on March 21 in USA, but spring starts on March 1 in Russia, Ukraine, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you have typos in your query... you misplaced all brackets e.g. this:

```
WHEN (MONTH(`birth_date` <= 6)) THEN
```

Should be:

```
WHEN (MONTH(`birth_date`) <= 6) THEN
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a logical error in your code in every WHEN line of the CASE. For example, if `birth_date` is `1982-04-01` then:

```
(MONTH(`birth_date` <= 6))
```

evaluates to

`(MONTH(true))`

because you put the brackets in the wrong place - it evaluates the statement

```
`birth_date` <= 6
```

and then passes the result of that to the `MONTH()` function. And of course `MONTH(true)` is nonsensical and returns `NULL`. The inner bracket should be round the `birth_date` field only, since that's the bit you want to get the month from!

Here's a working version:

```
SELECT *,
CASE 
  WHEN MONTH(`birth_date`) <= 3 THEN 'winter'
  WHEN MONTH(`birth_date`) <= 6 THEN 'spring'
  WHEN MONTH(`birth_date`) <= 9 THEN 'summer'
  WHEN MONTH(`birth_date`) <= 12 THEN 'autumn'
END AS `seasons`
FROM `students`;
```

(I couldn't see a need for the

```
(1 <= MONTH(`birth_date`))
```

part either, btw, and all the outer brackets are redundant).

And here's a working demonstration, with some sample data: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/giQczqKvJNbdCJFwevJCk8/5